# How to reject child Promise using AbortController

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, abortcontroller

I just learned about how to reject a Promise by using the [AbortController API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). It's working fine but when the promise to reject as a "child Promise", this one will still continue running even if the parent Promise is rejected.

Is there a way, when the parent is rejected, to stop the children too?

In this example, this means that there is no more `running` log after the `rejected` log when you click on the cancel button:

```js
let controller = new AbortController();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setInterval(() => console.log("running"), 500)

  controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => {
    console.log("rejected")
    reject();
  });

});

function cancel() {
  controller.abort();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cancel()">Cancel async loop</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise and abort controller are fine it's your timer function that needs to be cleared.

When you declare `setInterval` it returns an id that can be referenced later to clear the timer.

So, when you reject the promise you need to clear it.

```js
let controller = new AbortController();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const id = setInterval(() => console.log("running"), 500)

  controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => {
    console.log("rejected");
    clearInterval(id);
    reject();
  });

});

function cancel() {
  controller.abort();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cancel()">Cancel async loop</button>
```

Comment: Yes I mean yes  Nice catch and thanks for the ridiculously simple answer. I would have wasted so much time...